# How can I add URL parameters before page reloads or duplicates?

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, reload, page-refresh

How can I add URL parameters before reloading a page or duplicating the page?

Some pages on my Website can have multiple instances open each with unique session data. To keep track of the instance of the page, I use a parameter in the URL. I want clean URL's so I remove the parameters after the page loads.

I tried doing this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.history.pushState("", "Title", "/" + url + params);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
window.history.pushState(Object, Title, New-url);
```

Maybe you just didn't closed your "pushState" with ")" at the end?

You can try this as well:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { /* your pushState */ });
```

Comment: That's not the issue. I just made a typo in the example code that I posted.

Comment: can you try this:    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { //your pushState });